# Removing Column header in script output SQL

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, heading

```
SET HEADING OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF 
SET ECHO OFF
SET TERMOUT OFF
SET LINESIZE 2000
SET PAGESIZE 50000
SET SQLFORMAT ANSICONSOLE
```

This is what I use to clear the script output other than the data.

but the column names still keep showing up

Comment: `SET HEADING OFF` && `SET PAGES 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get to use the SQL*Plus style reporting OR the SET SQLFORMAT style - you don't get to use both.

So if you unset SQLFORMAT, your headers will go away